# How to submit to a captive portal form?

Tags: java, android, html, http, webview

Everytime i'm at university and i connect to WIFI, it opens an html page and asks me for my username and password.

This is why, I got the idea of making an application that can save my username and my password and send them to that html page that opens everytime i connect to the wifi of my university.
This is how i'll save time and of course I want to publish the app on my university website.

So I want to retrieve the username and the password from my TextBoxes and send them to html and let my application do the connect instead of I typing the authentications everytime.

Any idea how to do that?
Should I use the WebView? 
or it's better if I don't use the WebView because it's gonna connect invisibly and use something like Httprequest or something... I'm not familiar with those.

Solution:

5 years ago, I was a noob. 
Two methods:

1)Just see where the form is submitting the value by right clicking in chrome and inspecting the elements.

2) Use fiddler to intercept the http requests, then you will be able to know where it's posting.

Comment: html is for static page, it doesn't accept the request it for client side UI feature

Comment: @Pankaj kumar, thank you for encouraging new users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you make some kind of http request in you android app, that send your username and password as a post request.

On paper it should work, in reality I don't know. It depends on the which page the form gets processed I think.

But anything similair to this idea should/could work I think. I am still learning android. xD

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the security of your university website, you could first look at the source code of the site and see if it uses a form and what variables it needs to post. Then you implement a HttpPost in your app that posts those variables.

If the site changes a key on the site or uses some cookies or similar then it gets a little harder. You might then have to use a WebView. It has methods so that you can post javascript to the webview. You then do the usual

```
getElementById('IDofField').value = your username/password
```

and then do

```
getElementById('IDofForm').submit();
```

Take a look at the android developers site for a [guide on using webviews](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

Comment: the ids are respectively 'username' and 'password' , so it's not a matter of security, all i need to do is post the values. getElementById works on android?

Comment: Yes in the Web View you can use Javascript and you can make Java code that interacts and runs javascript in the web view. My idea was that you autofill the form on the website and the submits it with javascript from Java through the WebView.